# Google Sheets - Dynamic Cell Range For Data Validation, Specifically List Of Items Criteria

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am having some issues with specifying a dynamic cell range for a "data validation".

I'm aware you can do some tricky stuff with `= "Projections!M4:M"&O2`. You can update the content of cell `O2` for example to `3` and the output would be `Projections!M4:M3`.

This makes the value "dynamic". These tricks don't seem to work in the "Cell Range:" input field in the Data Validation selection/configuration screen.

My problem is, I hate seeing drop down arrows (call me o.c.d) for rows that have no content, my number of rows will grow in the future so I don't have any other option than selecting `M4:M`fills the whole 1002 rows with drop down arrows.

[image]

[image]

Has anyone worked out a trick to make dropdown arrows only show up for rows that are filled?

I'm using `= COUNTA(B4:B)`to get the number of rows that are filled and `= "Projections!M4:M"&O2` to make the desired `Projections!M4:MX` string but the "Cell Range" input field in the Data validation screen doesn't accept this as valid either.

Comment: Whomever downed voted and voted to close, why?

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find a direct solution, but something that I can work with to resolve my issue which was ***I hate seeing drop down arrows for empty rows.***

I turned a filter on for a column that will always be filled in and filtered by conditions `Cell is not empty` but i'd prefer a better solution.